# C++ calculating salary issue

Tags: c++, enums

Hello I am trying to make a program that will calculate an employees bonus when given his salary and job performance, although each time i run the code the bonus is calculated to 1 regardless of the salary I input. and I have to keep my function i created it is part of my homework. Any guidance on what the issue is would be appreciated

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
double bonus(double salary,int a);
int main()
{
    double salary;
    enum jobp{poor = 0,average = 1,good = 2};
    jobp performance;
    int a = performance;
    cout<<"Enter your salary and job performance (as a 0 for poor,1 for average and 2 for good)s$
    cin>>salary>>a;
    bonus(salary,a);
    cout<<"your bonus is "<<bonus;
    return 0;
}
double bonus(double salary, int a)
{
    double bonus;
if (a == 2)
{
    double c;
    c = .10;
    bonus = salary * c;
    return bonus;
}
else if (a  == 1)
{
    double b;
    b = .05;
    bonus = salary * b;
    return bonus;
}
else
{
    return 0;
}
}
```

Comment: Your bonus function returns a value, you might want to start there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi this should help you fix your problem.
Change this:

```
cout<<"Enter your salary and job performance (as a 0 for poor,1 for average and 2 for good)s$
cin>>salary>>a;
bonus(salary,a);
cout<<"your bonus is "<<bonus;
```

To this:

```
cout << "Enter your salary and job performance (as a 0 for poor,1 for average and 2 for good)" <<endl;
cin >> salary >> a;
cout << "your bonus is " << bonus(salary, a);
```

Answer (score 0):

catch the value of returned bonus

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
double bonus(double salary,int a); //this is for function right?
int main()
{
    double salary;
    double bonus; //create a variable for bonus
    enum jobp{poor = 0,average = 1,good = 2};
    jobp performance;
    int a = performance;
    cout<<"Enter your salary and job performance (as a 0 for poor,1 for average and 2 for good)s$
    cin>>salary>>a;
    bonus = bonus(salary,a); //catch the return
    cout<<"your bonus is "<<bonus;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to have the user to enter salary and performance separately.

```
cout << "Please enter your salary: " << endl;
cin >> salary;
cout "Please  job performance (as a 0 for poor,1 for average and 2 for good)" << endl;
cin >> a;
```